# Which prime factors of $8^{8^8}+1$ are known?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

We have the partial factorization

$$8^{8^8}+1=(2^{2^{24}}+1)\cdot (2^{2^{25}}-2^{2^{24}}+1)$$

The first factor is $F_{24}$. It is composite, but no prime factor is known.
A prime factor of the second factor must have the form $2^{25}\cdot 3k+1$.
The second factor can be written as $F_{25}-F_{24}+1$

> Is it known whether it is prime ?
>
> If no, is a prime factor known ?

Comment: The second factor has $10,100,891$ digits and has no prime factor below $10^{12}$

Comment: According to a more effecient calculation with GAP, there should be no prime factor below $6\cdot 10^{16}$

Comment: How do we know F24 is composite but do not know any prime factors?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN It is much easier to test whether a number is prime, than finding a prime factor, especially in the case $N=a^k\pm 1$, where $k$ is large.